# Apply dotnet-format on save in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, prettier, dotnet-format

I just discovered [`dotnet-format`](https://github.com/dotnet/format), but as far as I understand it's a command line tool that has to be called manually. How can I apply `dotnet-format` on saving a file in Visual Studio 2019? (not Visual Studio Code!)

Comment: See [Format document on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mynkow.FormatdocumentonSave) extension

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ah thanks, got it that dotnet-format is simply the command line tool for the built-in Visual Studio formatting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This setting enables code style enforcement on build. Any code style violations will be reported as build warnings or errors according to the .editorconfig file.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not what the question was about, I have dotnet-format setup to run as a pre-commit hook.

```
#!/bin/sh
dotnet-format
exit 0
```

For the on-save formatting and other gimmicks, I use CodeMaid. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCadwallader.CodeMaid

Comment: My only issue with this approach is that the developer has to install the pre-hook library for this to be triggered. I'm looking for a native solution that works without installing extra tools. Maybe at Build time as a BuildTask, or even using git itself without external dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your project to run this command automatically before build. But it will consume build time

```
<Project>
    <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="dotnet format --severity warn --verbosity diagnostic" />
</Target>
```